# Auto Pause or Play HTML5 Video on Hover

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am trying to program a section of a page that has three buttons. Each button should fade out the current video and begin to play video associated with that button. That video should play until you click on another button at which time it fades out and pauses and the new video fades in and begins to play. I have the fadeIn/fadeOut all in place, but am having some issue hooking up the pause and play functionality. Any ideas?

Here is the jQuery I have so far:

```
$('.hover-text div[class^="slide"]').hover(
    function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
          $('.slides div').fadeOut();
        };
        var class = $(this).attr('class');
        $('.slides div.' + class).fadeIn('slow');
        $('div[class^="slide"]').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

    },
    function () {

    }
);
```

I found [this tutorial](http://ecommercedeveloper.com/articles/1878-Hover-to-Play-Ecommerce-Videos-with-HTML5-CSS-and-JavaScript/), but I am not sure how to incorporate that code into mine.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/pNbYq/4/

```
$('#button-holder a').hover(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    if(!$('#'+that.data('video')).is(':visible')){
        $('video:visible')[0].pause();
        $('video:visible').fadeOut('normal', function(){
            $('#'+that.data('video')).fadeIn('normal', function(){
                $('#'+that.data('video'))[0].play();
            });
        });
    }else{
        $('#'+that.data('video'))[0].play();
    }
}, function(){
    $('video:visible')[0].pause();
});
```

Comment: Close. I actually want the video to play and pause on hover, so no clicking is necessary. The video should continue to play until you hover over another button. Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make that happen? Thanks so much for your help @Adam!

Comment: @Andrew I updated the code and the demo. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.