# Youtube/vimeo/any Video thumbnail that plays on hover (no pop up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, youtube

I need to create youtube/vimeo/any video thumbnails that play On mouse Hover. Could somebody please teach me how to do this? I am guessing javascript, but have not got anywhere through research. I do not want a pop up, just simply for the video to remain the same size as the thumbnail and play.

I will have a page full of them in a 10x5 grid, in the end.

Thank you

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556552/auto-pause-or-play-html5-video-on-hover

Comment: Hi I saw this before I posted however what I need is to hover over thumbnails and the video to load within the exact dimensions of the thumbnail. So the thumbnail is the link, as well as the placeholder for the video. This tutorial had seperate text links.

Comment: So why not just use the same code, but target the container of the video on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` you can play/pause the video on hovering... Something like this should work:

Javascript

```
$("#video-holder").mouseenter(function(){
    document.getElementById('video1').play();
});
$("#video-holder").mouseleave(function(){
    document.getElementById('video1').pause();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="video-holder">
    <video id="video1">
        <source src="..." type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yD49P/

Comment: Hi thanks it has worked brilliantly, is there a way though that when you hover over, as well as the video starting that I could make the background change to an image too? Sorry to be a pain

Comment: @user3277125 I'm confused, the background of the video? You wouldn't be able to see that...

Comment: I just mean if I added a div begind it or made the existing video-holder larger

Comment: @user3277125 Then you would add to the two functions above. Use something like `.css()` to change the background color or url