# How could I make embedded videos thumbnail automatically in HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, thumbnails

I'm basically new to coding, right now I'm studying web design at university and they gave us this homework where we have to create a website like youtube with a large amount of videos +200 (idk why it couldn't be 10 videos)

Right now I'm facing this problem of thumbnails, I really want it to look good, and have responsive thumbnails such as youtube, where you can put the mouse over the video's thumbnail and it will play a part of it.

I'm using  for videos, and for the right-bar how could I place the videos thumbnails as I said before.
Since it will be a large amount of videos I don't feel like making a gif, or a personalized video for each video, is there a way I can automate this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712825/youtube-vimeo-any-video-thumbnail-that-plays-on-hover-no-pop-up : I think this might help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712825/youtube-vimeo-any-video-thumbnail-that-plays-on-hover-no-pop-up

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand - are you asking how to make a thumbnail from each video? What code do you have already - is it just a series of <video src="test.mp4"></video>? If so do you want to run through them all creating a thumbnail, e.g. a png for each?

Comment: have a look at something like https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#preview-thumbnails

Comment: Thanks everybody I'll be reading those posts once I finish my class!

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using a series of <iframe></iframe> inside of different div classes atm and would like to make some kind of bot script for taking thumbnails from a embedded url whenever I upload a new link into my database